# Node with Async/Await - How to get specific line where error happened?

Tags: node.js, async-await, pg-promise

I have a function in node which looks like this:

```
async someFlow() {
        try {
            func1();
            func2();
            await getSomeData();
            func3();
        }
        catch (e) {
            sentryIo.captureException(e);
        }
    }
```

and getSomeData() looks like this:

```
async getSomeData() {
        //... some code
        await pgPromise.one('select * from some bad syntax') // line 351!!
        //... some code
    }
```

When pgPromise (which is a lib for talking to PostgreSQL) throws an error, the error's stack trace contains only the **internal line numbers** of the pgPromise lib at which the error happend.

So when the error is being catched and logged to the Sentry.io service I can't know the exact line of the error.

How can I make it so that the error will conatin the stack trace that tells me **the error happend in line 351**

Comment: Can you possibly show what you're actualy getting now? By default you get last 10 lines of error stack. If you need more you may want to try increase the number of lines either like this `Error.stackTraceLimit = 1000;` or start your app like this `node --stack-trace-limit=1000 main-file.js`

Comment: With `pg-promise` you can set it to use `bluebird` as the promise library, which in turn supports long-stack traces that you can enable and see complete stacks.

Comment: @vitaly-t Thanks! setting to long-stack traces worked! you can answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up doing:

```
var bb = require('bluebird');
bb.config({longStackTraces: true});
var pgp = require('pg-promise')({promiseLib: bb});
```

which gave me the complete stack trace for promises.

---

Memo from the author of [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise):

Make sure to have the Long Stack Traces disabled when it goes into production, as  sometimes those can have dramatic impact on the performance and memory consumption.